# Is there a way to restore SQL database while skipping some log files?

Tags: sql-server

From what I understand a transactional log file will store the transactions made after the last transactional log back up.

Lets say I have a database with 10 entries. I take a full back up.
I insert one entry, take a log back up (log1.trn)
I insert one entry, take another log back up (log2.trn)

Why does ssms not allow me to restore the database with the full back uo and log2.trn skipping log1.trn file?

Greatly appreciate any help thanks!

I have tried using T-sql to accomplish this as well but to no avail.

The error i receive is

> Msg 4305, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
> The log in this backup set begins at LSN 528000018207200001, which is too recent to apply to the database. An earlier log backup that includes LSN 525000023381600001 can be restored.
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
> RESTORE LOG is terminating abnormally.

Answer (score 6):

No.

Because you'd lose some of the transactions that happened on the server.

You always have to follow the correct [Restore sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/plan-and-perform-restore-sequences-full-recovery-model?view=sql-server-ver16) in order to restore your database to a consistent state.

1. Restore the full backup you want to start from
2. (Optionally) Restore the latest differential backup
3. Restore all the log files starting from that full/differential in correct sequence

You can find more information about this as well when looking for "Backup chain"

It's important to know that log backups contain all of the transactions from the latest transactional backup, and after a transaction log backup, the log file gets cleared.

An example would be:

- You create a new table : dbo.PleaseDontLoseMe
- Transaction log backup 1 taken here -> Log gets cleared --
- INSERT INTO dbo.PleaseDontLoseMe
- Transaction log backup 2 taken here -> Log gets cleared --

Now we restore the database and we skip Log backup 1, SQL would be trying to insert a record in a table that wasn't ever made.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does SSMS not allow me to restore the database with the full back up and log2.trn skipping log1.trn file?

Given such an *over-simplified* example, I can see why you would think this should be possible.

In reality, your database is doing loads of stuff for itself, all the time, and every change is logged as transactions and *then* there's all the *myriad* of changes it's taking from Users.
Recovering a database is about getting a "broken" database back into a working state - as it was at a given point in time, starting from a known, fixed point (the last full backup).  That means that *everything* that it did (since that last backup) has to be done *again*, in exactly the *same way* as it was before.  You cannot "miss bits out" because there's just no capability to do so.

If you *could*, somehow, "record" all the SQL that was "thrown at" the database, then you could "edit" that stream to remove any bits you didn't want and "replay" that.  But that's nothing whatever to do with *Recovering* your database.

Answer (score 0):

Changed records since last backup are flagged. When you backup - full, diff, or log, those flags are reset.

You can skip restoring log 1 if you have a differential backup after it to restore. Restore full, diff, log2.

Else you need to supply all changes since the full backup for data consistency (truth) to prevail. You'd corrupt your data without the safeguard of sequentially applying all transactions.